# Qt override widget shortcut (window shortcut)

Tags: qt

I have a Qt app with several window shortcuts defined in a Qt Designer form action. The shortcuts works well until they are pressed while the focus is on a widget that handles the same combination (overriding my window shortcut).

I would like to have the opposite behavior: window shortcuts overriding focused widget shortcuts.

I tried using `eventFilter` and I can catch the desired events, but I'm not able to resend them in a way that the global shortcuts are called. I could use a big switch and call the actions myself, but of course, I would like to avoid that.

I used `postEvent` and `sendEvent` inside the `eventFilter` using the `MainWindow` as the receiver, but the events are ignored:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent* event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Z
            && keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier) {
            //Calling the triggers directly works
            ui->actionUndo->trigger();
            return true;
        } else if (keyEvent->modifiers().testFlag(
                       Qt::KeypadModifier)) {
            QKeyEvent* ev2
                = new QKeyEvent(keyEvent->type(), keyEvent->key(), 0);
            qDebug() << keyEvent << ev2;
            //This sendEvent doesn't work
            QApplication::sendEvent(ui->widget, ev2);
            event->accept();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You just need to use `QShortcut` with `Qt::ApplicationShortcut` context. Or I don't understand your logic and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you try posting to `qApp` instead of some widget?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I tried Qt::ApplicationShortcut and the result is the same

Comment: @king_nak I just tried that too and the same... :(

Comment: Is the 0 in sendEvent that doesn't work correct? It is stated to be a _Qt::KeyboardModifiers_, and may be that's why your re-send events are not treated correctly? Mean, you check if received event has one, and then resend the new event without it.

Comment: @MikhailChurbanov I tried using "keyEvent->modifiers()" instead of 0 and nothing changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one of the solutions you can install [QEvent::ShortcutOverride](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#details) event filters:

> For QEvent::ShortcutOverride the receiver needs to explicitly accept
>   the event to trigger the override. Calling ignore() on a key event
>   will propagate it to the parent widget. The event is propagated up the
>   parent widget chain until a widget accepts it or an event filter
>   consumes it.

That event would be called when some widget tries to override a shortcut event, e.g. just a simple example:

I have just a new Qt app with one lineEdit and window menu with Ctrl+V shortcut (overrides the paste shortcut in lineEdit).

Here how it works:

1.Create the filtering method that would ignore (return `true`) the shortcut overrides (I've used `MainWindow::eventFilter` in sample app, however you can use any filtering object you need or want). It might be better to follow Qt docs and use the accept()/ignore() as stated above, however on my app it worked just fine without them just returning true/false.

2.Install the event filter from p.1 to widget that should ignore shortcut action if overriding.

3.I've added the menu action with Ctrl+V shortcut in designer. In code below you would see the `"Hello from window shortcut!"` - the menu action result, when trying to Paste (Ctrl+V) instead of actual lineEdit paste operation.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        // Ignore only the Ctrl + V shortcut override, you can customize check for your needs
        if (keyEvent->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) && keyEvent->key() == 'V') {
            qDebug() << "Ignoring" << keyEvent->modifiers() << "+" << (char)keyEvent->key() << "for" << watched;
            event->ignore();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}

void MainWindow::on_action1_triggered()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello from window shortcut!";
}
```

Sample debug output:

> Ignoring QFlags(ControlModifier) + V for QLineEdit(0x575b10, name = "lineEdit")
>
> Hello from window shortcut!

Note: Unfortunatelly you should install such filters for all widgets you want not to override the shortcuts manually.

**UPDATE:** Shortly - you are ignoring the underlying widget shortcut event and propagating it to the parent widget.

Below is comparison for Ctrl-Z (triggers Undo in edit) and Ctrl-V (ignored in edit instead of Paste, and triggers menu Action):

**Block I - events in beginning are the same for both Ctrl-Z and ignored Ctrl-V:**

1. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(ShortcutOverride, Key_Control, ControlModifier)
2. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Control, ControlModifier)
3. MainWindow recieves QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Control, ControlModifier)
4. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(ShortcutOverride, Key_Z, ControlModifier)

**Block II - where the difference happens...**

For Ctrl-Z - lineEdit receives the Ctrl+Z KeyPress event, triggering the Undo operation:

1. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Z, ControlModifier)

   *Here the MainWindow recieves no events, not depending of has it Ctrl+Z action shortcuts or not, it's just swallowed by QLineEdit*

For Ctrl-V - MainWindow receives the Ctrl+V ShortcutOverride event propagated from QLineEdit:

1. Ignoring "Ctrl+V" for QLineEdit code executes in `filterEvent`
2. MainWindow recieves QKeyEvent(ShortcutOverride, Key_V, ControlModifier)
3. "Hello from window shortcut!" code from menu Action triggered slot executed.

   *Here the QLineEdit receives no events after filter tells it to ignore ShortcutOverride, the MainWindow shortcut executed instead*

**Block III - events in ending are also the same for both Ctrl-Z and ignored Ctrl-V - just key release events:**

1. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Z, ControlModifier)
2. MainWindow recieves QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Z, ControlModifier)
3. QLineEdit  recieves QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Control)
4. MainWindow recieves QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Control)

**P.S. I really don't know why it happens the exactly so - but this is just how it works :)**

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but I didn't understand it very well... Am I overriding accepting the window shortcut, or I am disabling the override of the child (LineEdit in this case)? Can you post what happens when the user press a key and the difference of function calls when the window shortcut overrides?

Comment: Oh, I honestly, don't understand why Qt Events flows exactly in the manner I've observe, but I've updated the answer, trying to show and explain the difference as I see it.